# In Jmeter calculate time taken to get a specific response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, response-time

I am using a while loop to run a API request until a specific response is recieved (eg. Job status). Now, I want to calculate time taken for a job to reach that status. I want to generate a report with jobID, status and the time taken. Is there a way to do that? Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQVpK.png)

While condition that i am using: ${__jexl3(${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 300 && "${Status}"!="Ready",)}

Answer (score 0):

Put everything under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it will return the cumulative time of all its children execution

[image]

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)

Comment: I am using the summary report which gives this information. But, i want to capture the time for the job to reach status. I am using while controller with 300 attempts but, sometimes the status change happens even before 300 attempts so, i want to capture for every job  to what is the time taken. Is this possible or is it only the average report that we can get?